# Ubuntu 12.10 fails to reconnect to wireless

Tags: 12.10, wireless

On 12.10 if my laptop goes to sleep (i.e. by closing the lid) or restarts it fails to connect to my wifi again. Deleting the connection in edit connections allows me to reconnect by reentering the password but I don't want to have to do this every time. Any idea on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Bad luck - this is a well known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/854833).